# Creating circle polygons that do not appear distorted at high latitude in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, rasterization

I would like to create a shapefile with a number of circle polygons, which I would like to show on a globe. I need to rasterize these circles using EPSG:4326 so it works on the globe I am using. I am using gdal_rasterize to do this. The problem I am currently having is that the circles are being distorted as the geotiff is being projected onto the globe.

How can I fix this problem using ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Did you tried to change the polygon CRS?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS/QGIS/OGR you wish to ask about in this particular question.  That way you will be able to provide a detailed description of what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Cartesian circles in decimal degrees have no practical use (except to flag questionable analysis). Please [Edit] the question to include your purpose in attempting this.

Comment: I've reduced the scope of and reopened your question so that you can cut/paste your answer from within the area reserved for your question into the area reserved for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution in ArcGIS. In the editor, under Advanced options, there is the "Construct Geodetic" option. This allows you to create lines and polygons that retain their shape and do not distort.

Comment: This answer does not correlate with the question. Geodetic circles *should* appear distorted in a *plate carrée* canvas.